# why following code is not generate proper output base on input date

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, date-formatting

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
date1 = dateFormat.format(new Date(date));
System.out.println(date+" "+date1);
```

My input is `date = 30-Dec-2019` and the expected output is `2019-12-30`

The output I'm getting is `2020-12-30`

Comment: Do not longer use the old simpledateformat and java.util.Date Api. Use the new java.times.* API. And yyyy instead of YYYY.

Comment: If you want help with your code using the obsolete API, at least post code that compiles.

Comment: The deprecated `Date(String)` constructor doesn't accept input in that format.

Comment: I recommend (1) Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) Even if you insist on using `Date`, stay far away from the deprecated constructors. They have been deprecated for over 23 years because they work  unreliably across time zones.

Comment: using small yyyy i solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the outdated date/time API. Do it using modern date/time API as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String strDate = "30-Dec-2019";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, inputFormat);
        System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-12-30
```

Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn about the drawbacks of the outdated date/time API and the benefits of modern date/time API.